# NVM node_modules or install location

Tags: node.js, node-modules, nvm

NVM node_modules or install location ?

There is no provision by NVM itself to give installation file path after

```
nvm -v
```

Install location for `node_modules` should be known for troubleshoot purpose

Answer (score 3):

What you're looking for is `npm list -g`. This will show you the global modules, which I assume you're looking for. Otherwise, it's in the node_modules folder.